# How can I use a simple phrase to express "the location to get one's gift card"

Tags: word-request

Like the word style of `billing address`, I want to find a simple phrase with "xxx address/location" to express the meaning of "the location to get one's gift card"

I tried to create by my own, but something like `gift card collect location` doesn't looks professional.

Any suggestions are highly appreciate!

================ 
UPDATED

I want put a sign on my website to make people know where to get(purchased online, just go and get it) those gift cards offline (at some certain stores), so I'd like to write something like: GIFT CARD (collect/pick/get/....) LOCATION: address1/address2/.... more addresses

Comment: Could you say more about "*one's* gift card”? "one's" as a possessive indicates ownership, but I think by saying "to get" you mean to go buy one. You wouldn't buy something that belongs to you. Maybe you mean "the location to get *myself/someone* a gift card”?

Comment: If you store your gift cards on a shelf, you could call it your "gift card shelf". This could even work figuratively on a website.

Comment: @user3169 I want put a sign on my website to make people know where to get(purchased online, just go and get it) those gift cards offline (at some certain stores), so I'd like to write something like: GIFT CARD (collect/pick/get/....) LOCATION: address1/address2/.... more addresses

Comment: Thanks for updating. Sufficient context should always be added so it is clear what you are trying to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you mean you would like to purchase a gift card, since these days, most gift cards are either given or mailed directly to the recipient.

The simple request

> Where can I get/purchase a gift card?
>   Where are gift cards?

should do the trick.

If you are instructing someone to pick up a gift card after ordering on-line, you might use

> You can **pick up** your gift card at any of our conveniently located stores (AmE)
>   You can **collect** your gift card at any of our stores (BrE)
>   You can **get** your gift card at any of our collection points, terms and conditions apply. (BrE)

and then list the different locations they can get their gift card(s).

Comment: TY for your answer. I want put a sign on my website to make people know where to get(purchased online, just go and get it) those gift cards offline (at some certain stores), so I'd like to write something like: GIFT CARD (collect/pick/get/....) LOCATION: address1/address2/.... more addresses

Comment: Added to my answer to answer your comment.

Comment: I wouldn't use *collect* in AmE.

Comment: Thank for explaining those 3 words. How can I use it in my phrase ? obviously I can't simply write `card get location` on my sign. @Peter

Comment: For AmE: "card pick-up location"